# Speed Up Filter Check in Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a Grails 2.1.1 project using the Spring Security Core plugin.

I'm using a custom filter that makes a POST call to an external service to verify credentials (similar to CAS). This takes time and over the course of loading my web application, several hundred POST calls are made.

Is there a way I could "cache" the credentials for a period of time so that a POST call is not made for every single request for restricted content?

I've thought about setting a variable in the session, but it seems as though Spring Security would have something to cache this request built-in.

To look at it another way, if I integrated Spring Security with a CAS service, how would I configure Spring Security so that after the first time a restricted resource is called for, it would bypass checking the ticket against the server for a period of time (4-8 hours)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question up. I ended up saving some credentials to the user's session and first checking to see if the user had a valid session. If so, I avoided the extra expensive call to the validation service.